# Django SerializerMethodField vs Complex SQL

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

I'm wondering about what people think about the tradeoffs of efficiency and readability between using Django's `SerializerMethodField` and writing potentially convoluted SQL. I'm think SQL would generally be quicker, but the complexity of code may not be worth it. I lean towards using the `SerializerMethodField` for better readability/maintainability, but am curious what others think.

This isn't a great example and just serves as an introduction to what I am talking about. These SQL queries could get much more convoluted. I know this code probably isn't actually written perfectly.

```py
# Comment
# is_admin: Boolean
# public_email: String
# email: Optional String

default_email = 'foo@bar.com'
```

```py
queryset = Comment.objects

class CommentSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    is_admin = serializers.BooleanField()
    email = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    @staticmethod
    def get_email(comment):
        if comment.is_admin:
            return comment.public_email
        return comment.email or default_email
```

```py
queryset = Comment.objects.annotate(
    email=Case(
        When(is_admin=True, then='public_email'),
        default=Coalesce('email', Value(default_email)),
        output_field=CharField(),
    )
)

class CommentSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    is_admin = serializers.BooleanField()
    email = serializers.CharField()
```

Comment: Method get_email doesn't need @staticmethod

Comment: Annotations with logic are very helpfull when then filtering by it is used after